# How to implement the cordova-plugin-datepicker for Android?

Tags: android, cordova, datepicker, datetimepicker, timepicker

I have tried to implement this Datetimepicker ( https://github.com/VitaliiBlagodir/cordova-plugin-datepicker ) but still not working on my Android Device ( Android 4.0.4).

1. I added the plugin to my Project and used : cordova plugin add https://github.com/VitaliiBlagodir/cordova-plugin-datepicker.
2. Put a Trigger to my js file and tried to test a alert("test"). I get the test alert on browser and on Device, but no alert from Datetimepicker?
3. I also rm Android from Platform and build it again, everything is there, but still not working. ( To build the app, i am using PhoneGap Build)
4. I have no idea what I am missing? .... any help would be nice :-).

---

Example:

in Html

```
<input type="text"  onclick="calendar()" />
```

in JS

```
<script>

function calendar(){

  alert("test")  //  is working

  var options = {
    date: new Date(),
    mode: 'date'
  };

  datePicker.show(options, function(date){
   alert("date result " + date);     // not working
  });

}

</script>
```

---

Comment: Also this is a native plugin so won't work on a browser

Comment: It is working my android app. You should also add error method.Check your console log and post your error when calendar method get fired.

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to add the script in your path.

Make sur you have register the plugin to your config.xml like so :

```
<feature name="DatePicker">
  <param name="ios-package" value="DatePicker"/>
</feature>

<feature name="DatePickerPlugin">
  <param name="android-package" value="com.okaybmd.cordova.plugin.datepicker.DatePickerPlugin"/>
</feature>
```

(more info @ http://phonegap-plugins.com/plugins/okaybmd/cordova-plugin-datepicker )

The plugin won't work in your browser.
You have to test it through your device or an emulator.

Answer (score 0):

Did you include your script in your HTML ?

```
<script src="your/path/DatePicker.js"></script>
```

Comment: Yes, i tried also to copy the DatePicker.js from the Plugin  /www/android/DatePicker.js  and put it in my path, but still not working. Maybe someone can show an working Example with html and javascript ?

Comment: I didn't use this plugin so I can't help you there.
Maybe this plugin need jQuery?

Comment: Well i don't know then sorry :(  All I can do is upvote your question, good luck !

Comment: Did you find a solution for this after all?

Comment: I'm in the exact same boat. No solutions as far as I can tell. It's too bad the repository does not include a full example.

Comment: Plugin is not required to add path in your index

Answer (score 0):

The datepicker returns a promise, so you need to handle that on your code.

```
<script>

function calendar(){

  alert("test")  //  is working

  var options = {
    date: new Date(),
    mode: 'date'
  };

  datePicker.show(options).then(function(date){
   alert("date result " + date);
  });

}

</script>
```

Also, I have always used this with Angular, so not completely sure on how you inject the service for your usage.

Reference: http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/datePicker/

Answer (score -1):

I used it for developing and Ionic app. The idea was to simply add the plugin (datepicker) and include `ngCordova` and `ngCordovaMocks` js files in your resources and the HTML.

`ngCordovaMocks` is for web development.

The injection was done while building apk or ipa at the main module

```
app.module('asas',['ngCordova'],function($cordovaDatePicker){

}).run()
```